# how to break x axis to visualize all data

Tags: plotting

I have four datasets (dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD), out of which two have the same plot range of X axis and rest two have different range of X axis.
Here is the code:

```
dataA = {{0, 80}, {0.01, 40}, {0.02, 20}, {0.05, 10}};

dataB = {{0, 80}, {0.01, 65}, {0.05, 10}, {0.1, 12}, {0.2, 
    020}, {0.3, 25}, {0.375, 51}};

dataC = {{0, 80}, {0.5, 65}, {010, 89}, {50, 110}, {100, 
    121}, {300, 135}};

dataD = {{0, 80}, {30, 200}, {150, 350}, {300, 470}};

Plot1 = 
 ListPlot[{dataA, dataB}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
  PlotMarkers -> {●, ▼}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}]
```

[image]

```
Plot2 = 
     ListPlot[{dataC, dataD}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
      PlotMarkers -> {▲, ■}, 
      PlotStyle -> {Gray, Red}]
```

[image]

```
Show[Plot2, Plot1]
```

[image]

Now when I merge both plots (Plot1 and Plot2 by using Show) some data sets are not visualised, Data points of plot1 are showing just like a point, I understand that I need to break X axis, but I could not do it in mathematica.
Any help will be great for me, i am using mathematica 9.

Comment: I think you may try using `Overlay`. Use `Frame->True` for each plot and label the two sets of ticks on two different edges. Then overlay the two plots. What `Show` does is combining all graphic elements on the same canvas with their specified positions; this is why the range of your `dataA` `dataB` looks really narrow.

Comment: Have you considered a different layout, using `ListLogLinearPlot`?

Answer (score 5):

As [shown by @kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/242132/36508), you can use [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid) for this purpose. With the `"MergeAxes"` option, you can even get nice axes breaks. Since in your case, both axes of the plots are wildly different, we can create a 2x2 grid of plots and fill the two empty corners with `Graphics[{},Frame->True]` type plots:

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 {
  {
   Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> 10000, Frame -> True],
   Show[Plot2, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {85, Automatic}}, Frame -> True]
   },
  {
   Show[Plot1, Plot2, Frame -> True],
   Frame[Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> 10000, Frame -> True]]
   }
  },
 PlotRange -> Min,
 "MergeAxes" -> "Cut",
 Spacings -> 10,
 ItemSize -> {{1, 2}, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Some notes:

- <s>The current version of `PlotGrid` has an issue that causes too many axes break indicators to appear. I have submitted a fixed version, in the meantime you can manually work around this issue as shown at the bottom of this answer</s> *Note: This has been fixed by now*
- I set the `PlotRange` of the two filler plots to a large value so that I can then use `PlotRange->Min` on the entire `PlotGrid` to make all ranges consistent (the `10000` essentially needs to be bigger than all plots ranges, such that the range of the actual plots is chosen). Alternatively you could set the plot ranges of the two filler plots manually, but that would require a lot of tweaking.
- I set the `ItemSize` of the first column to be smaller than the second to somehow hint at the fact that the first column covers a way smaller range. This can obviously be removed/tweaked if desired
- I combine the two plots in the bottom left to ensure that any points from `Plot2` in the range of `Plot1` are also shown
- I tweak the `PlotRange` of `Plot2` slightly so that the vertical ranges of the two rows don't overlap
- I set `Frame->True` for all plots since that's needed for `PlotGrid` to give us a nice frame with broken axes

## Workaround

*Note: the underlying issue has been fixed, so this is no longer relevant*

As noted above, the current version of `PlotGrid` has an issue that causes too many axes break indicators to appear:

[image]

To work around the issue until the updated version is accepted, we can manually set the `FrameStyle` of all four plots to have invisible (white) frames in towards the middle, and grey frames on the outside:

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][
 {
  {
   Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> 10000, Frame -> True,
    FrameStyle -> {{GrayLevel[0.4], White}, {White, GrayLevel[0.4]}}
    ],
   Show[Plot2, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {85, Automatic}},
    FrameStyle -> {{White, GrayLevel[0.4]}, {White, GrayLevel[0.4]}}
    ]
   },
  {
   Show[Plot1, Plot2,
    FrameStyle -> {{GrayLevel[0.4], White}, {GrayLevel[0.4], White}}
    ],
   Frame[Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> 10000, Frame -> True,
     FrameStyle -> {{White, GrayLevel[0.4]}, {GrayLevel[0.4], White}}]
    ]
   }
  },
 PlotRange -> Min,
 "MergeAxes" -> "Cut",
 Spacings -> 10,
 ItemSize -> {{1, 2}, 1}
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you, I am using Mathematica version 9. In another pc I have version 10, however, ResourceFunction is useful in mathematica 12. So has there any alternatives which work in 9?

Comment: @PPyne You can try to download the paclet version of `PlotGrid` from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d6rtu5kzs4q4lpv/PlotGrid-4.2.0.paclet?dl=1). To use it, install the paclet with `PacletInstall["path/to/PlotGrid-4.2.0.paclet"]`, and then simply replace `ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]` by `PlotGrid` in the code. I tested it in 10.4 (version 9 does not work), and it seems to mostly work. (the documentation page looks a bit funny sometimes because it was not designed for older versions)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Lukas Lang's [ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/):

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{
   {ListPlot[{dataA, dataB}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
    Frame -> True, 
    PlotMarkers -> {●, ▼}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}], 
   ListPlot[{dataC, dataD}, PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, All}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
    PlotMarkers -> {▲, ■}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Gray, Red}]}}, 
 ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Use the options `Spacings -> Scaled[.02]` and `"ShowFrameLabels" -> Automatic` to get:

[image]

To have the two plots separated with divider line with no ticks, use

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{
  {ListPlot[{dataA, dataB}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, 
    PlotMarkers -> {●, ▼}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green}], 
   ListPlot[{dataC, dataD}, PlotRange -> Automatic, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
    PlotMarkers -> {▲, ■}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Gray, Red}]}}, 
   ImageSize -> Large, AspectRatio -> 1/2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the breaking of the X-axis is not trivial in MMA.
Let's say, we have such data sets that exist in different x-ranges:

```
da = Table[{i, Log[i + 0.0001] Sin[12 Pi i]}, {i, 0, 0.1, 0.02}];
db = Table[{i, i^1.1 Sin[18 Pi i]}, {i, 0.5, 6, 0.2}];
```

Then we can draw them altogether using following simple way:

```
ma = MinMax[da[[All, 2]]];
mb = MinMax[db[[All, 2]]];
mm = Abs /@ {Min@Flatten@{ma, mb}, Max@Flatten@{ma, mb}};

mrk = Graphics[{Black, Thin,
    Line@{{{-0.05, -0.1}, {0.05, 0.1}},
      {{0.05, -0.1}, {0.15, 0.1}}}
    }, ImageSize -> 20];

pos=0.88;

res = GraphicsRow[{
   ListPlot[da,
    ImagePadding -> {{30, 0}, {30, 5}},
    PlotRange -> {{-0.005, 0.125}, {-1.2 First@mm, 1.2 Last@mm}},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameStyle -> {{Black, White}, {Black, Black}},
    ImageSize -> {500, 350}],
   ListPlot[db,
    ImagePadding -> {{0, 30}, {30, 5}},
    PlotRange -> {{0.35, 6}, {-1.2 First@mm, 1.2 Last@mm}},
    Frame -> True,
    FrameStyle -> {{White, Black}, {Black, Black}},
    ImageSize -> {500, 350}]
   },
  Spacings -> 0,
  Alignment -> Left,
  Epilog -> {
    Inset[mrk, Scaled@{pos, 0.15}],
    Inset[mrk, Scaled@{pos, 0.915}]}
  ]
```

[image]

There are some important things about this workaround:

1. the `pos` defines the x-position of marks that show break position. It should be adjusted manually for better view (in range 0-2).
2. The `ImageSize` definition in `ListPlot`'s should be with height values (they need to be adjusted for the aspect ratio of plots) otherwise the plots will not coincide at the middle.
3. Other values of plot heights require the another vertical positions for break markers inside the `Inset` because they have defined in `Scaled` form for simplicity.

Comment: FYI, You can use [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid) with the `"MergeAxes"` option to automate the creation of such plots, e.g. `ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{{ListPlot[da, Frame -> True], ListPlot[db, Frame -> True]}}, PlotRange -> Max, "MergeAxes" -> "Cut", Spacings -> 10]`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Overlay` (an example from my comment):

```
Plot1 = 
  ListPlot[{dataA, dataB}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
    PlotMarkers     -> {●, ▼}, 
    PlotStyle       -> {Blue, Green}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks      -> {{All, {{0, 400}}}, {All, {{0, 400}}}}, 
    FrameTicksStyle -> {{Automatic, Opacity[.0]}, {Automatic, Opacity[.0]}}]

Plot2 = 
  ListPlot[{dataC, dataD}, PlotRange -> Automatic, 
    PlotMarkers     -> {▲, ■}, 
    PlotStyle       -> {Gray, Red}, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks      -> {{{{0, 80}}, All}, {{{0, 80}}, All}}, 
    FrameTicksStyle -> {{Opacity[.0], Automatic}, {Opacity[.0], Automatic}}]
Overlay[{Plot1, Plot2}]
```

[image: Output]

You will of course need labels to clarify which is which, but this is basically the gist of it.

Comment: FYI, you can use [`ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots) with the `"AxesSides"` option to automate the creation of such plots, e.g. `ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][Show[Plot1, Frame -> True], Show[Plot2, Frame -> True], "AxesSides" -> "TwoXY"]`